# Static variable inside sub-scope

Tags: c++, static

Is a code like this erroneous or ok:

```
void fun()
{
    if ( CONDITION )
    {
        static MyClass myclass;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I.e., can static variables be declared inside local scope?

Comment: Yes, static variables in local scopes are initialised when the scope is first entered, but not destroyed until the program exits.

Comment: Yes. All local variables with static [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) works the same, never mind how many levels down they're nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly valid according to the C++ standard. It may be a questionable thing to do / bad practice in some cases, but it's valid and well defined.

Answer (score -1):

It can, of course. You can easily see that by trying to compile the code.